# No result using kivy.network.urlrequest-lib

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am using MacOS and python3.6. As I develop an App for Android I cannot use the normal **requests** library. I have to use **kivy.network.urlrequest**. But somehow for some links I don't get a result when I use the **kivy.network.urlrequest**-lib. But a request using the standard **requests**-lib gives a result for the exact same link. Please see the following code:

```
    from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    import requests
    import time
    link = "https://www.genius.com/Iron-Maiden-no-more-lies-lyrics"
    request_kivy = UrlRequest(link)
    while not request_kivy.is_finished:
        Clock.tick()
    print("This gives no result for me: ",request_kivy.result)
    print("This gives a result: ",requests.get(link).text[0:100])

    link = "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bacon"
    request_kivy = UrlRequest(link)
    while not request_kivy.is_finished:
        Clock.tick()
    print("Here both give a result, kivy: ",request_kivy.result[0:100])
    print("Here both give a result, standard: ",requests.get(link).text[0:100])
```

I get the following output:

```
This gives no result for me:  
This gives a result:  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="snarly apple_music_player--enabled bagon_song_page--enabled song_stor
Here both give a result, kivy:  b"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html il_EN il_EN'>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; ch"
Here both give a result, standard:  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html il_EN il_EN'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; ch
```

Comment: Your belief that you can't use requests is incorrect, using requests is fine. You'll have to take care of not blocking the gui yourself though, e.g. by running requests in a thread.

Comment: @inclement I tried a minimal example using "requests" and the App crashes. Unfortunately I cannot create the apk via buildozer using my mac. Therefore I use Ubuntu via VirtualBox to create the apk. This leads to the problem that Ubuntu doesn't detect my Smartphone connected via USB, therefore I cannot get any logs.... But I found that when I remove the "import requests" line, the app doesn't crash anymore. So I don't know if its possible to use "requests" for the APK.